how to conditionally extend generic interface based on parent keys
Consider these definitions:
interface A {
    id?: string;
    name?: string;
}

interface BaseLabel<B extends Parent, Parent extends A> {
    keyStr?: keyof B & string;
}

interface RequiredLabel<B extends Parent, Parent extends A> extends BaseLabel<B, A> {
    label: string;
}

interface OptionalLabel<B extends Parent, Parent extends A> extends BaseLabel<B, A> {
    label?: string;
}

type Final<B extends Parent, Parent extends A> = RequiredLabel<B, Parent> | OptionalLabel<B, Parent>

I need to refine Final type so that Parent keys should have a required label (based on RequiredLabel) while all other B keys can come with an optional label ( based on OptionalLabel).
interface Parent extends A {
    value?: string;
}

interface child extends Parent {
    isDate?: boolean;
}

const fields: Final[] = [
   {id: '1', name: '1', isDate: true},
   {id: '2', name: '2', isDate: true, label: 'label 2'},
   {id: '3', name: '3', value: '3', label: 'label 3'},
];

all records related to parent must have a mandatory label while other can have not.
Can anyone help me with this narrowing?

I cannot see that any type definition has key field. Should it be defined as a part of A type?

Sorry for that. It was a typo. I fixed it.

The first two values in the array don't extend Parent since they're missing the value property. They'd be considered totally unrelated types.

please consider it optional

"Consider these definitions" The RequiredLabel and OptionalLabel definitions are weird because they don't use their type parameters. Why do they take B and Parent at all? And later you write Final[], but Final needs type arguments. What do you want them to be? It's not obvious to me what the intent here is. Please [edit] to fix unused type params and clarify your use case.

Here is the solution that worked for me:
interface RequiredLabel<B extends Parent, Parent extends A> {
    keyStr: keyof Parent & string;
    label: string;
}

interface OptionalLabel<B extends Parent, Parent extends A> {
    keyStr: keyof Omit<B, keyof Parent> & string;
    label?: string;
}

type Final<B extends Parent, Parent extends A> = RequiredLabel<B, Parent> | OptionalLabel<B, Parent>


This solution doesn't compile with your example in the question. Generic type 'Final' requires 2 type argument(s).(2314) - error at the line where you declared const fields: Final[]
